# IE9 SDK with Windows SDK

Tags: internet-explorer-9, bho

I wonder what is the best strategy for using the new IE9 interfaces. Microsoft provides a IE9 SDK ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740471), under "Headers and Libraries" link), which will create a new folder under '*%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Internet Explorer*'.

However, trying to use this SDK naively (i.e. adding the Include folder to the search path) is a mess. Reason is that other include files, from the Platform SDK or from Visual Studio (for example: 'atlhost.h', will include files such as mshtml.h). When included from Platform SDK header, the mshtml.h of the platform will take precedence. When included from my own stdafx.h, the IE9 will be included. At the end, I cannot trust which file is included from where.

I've slip-streamed (copy over) the headers and libraries into the Platform SDK, but I've a strong feeling this is the wrong solution. I wonder if anyone has a better strategy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the SDK ahead of Windows SDK in include and lib search path or in case of Visual C++ 2010, keep the inherited values but replace the default values with the IE SDK paths.